# Как передать массив строк функции на чистом си?

Tags: c, функции

Изучая си, столкнулся с проблемой: получается, не могу передать массив строк ( или структур? ) в функцию.

Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef char string [ 32 ];

void find_repeat (string * massive);

// MAIN FUNC <--
int main( void )
{
string massive[] = { "name", "test", "name", "need", "you", "need", "me", "test" };
find_repeat(massive);

return 0;
}

// FIND REPEAT <--

void find_repeat( string * massive )
{
bool var;
int size = (sizeof(massive) / sizeof(massive[0]));
fprintf( stdout, "The size of temp_massive: %d\n\n", size );
int index = 0;
string temp_massive [ size ];

for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) 
{
    string temp_el; 
    strcpy( temp_el, massive[i] );
    var = true;
    for( int j = 0; (j < size) && var; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(temp_el, temp_massive[j]) == 0)
        {
            var = false;
        }               

        else if(j == (size - 1)) 
        {
            strcpy( temp_massive[ index ], massive[ i ] );
            index++;    
        }
    }
}

for ( int i = 0; i < index; i++ )
{
    fprintf( stdout, "Member #%d of temp_massive: %s\n", i, temp_massive[i]         );
}
}
```

Comment: По-моему и вам в том числе уже писали -- не делайте typedef на указатели (и массивы).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

На уровне сухой педантичной терминологии языка С массив, как таковой, невозможно никуда передать. Голые массивы в С являются некопируемыми объектами. Передать куда-то можно либо *указатель на весь массив*, либо *указатель на его начальный элемент*.

Именно указатель на начальный элемент массива вы и передаете в своем коде. Но после такой передачи определить размер исходного массива внутри функции уже невозможно, ибо никакого массива у вас там уже нет - есть только *указатель* на элемент.

Поэтому вот про это внутри вашей функции

```
int size = (sizeof(massive) / sizeof(massive[0]));
```

вы можете сразу забыть. Это работает только с *массивами*, но не с указателями. Поэтому если вы собрались передавать указатель на элемент, то размер массива придется передавать отдельно

```
void find_repeat( string * massive, int size )
```

(Я бы предпочел использовать `unsigned` или `size_t` для представления размера массива, но раз уж вы используете `int`, то пусть будет `int`).

Соответственно вызывать вашу функцию вы сможете как

```
string massive[] = { "name", "test", "name", "need", "you", "need", "me", "test" };
find_repeat(massive, sizeof massive / sizeof *massive);
```

В этом контексте трюк с `sizeof` сработает, т.е. здесь `massive` - это именно массив.

Что вы пытаетесь делать дальше внутри `find_repeat` и почему - не совсем понятно. (Идея, конечно, ясна, но реализация - хромает). В цикле у вас идет сравнение значений с элементами некоего массива `temp_massive`. Но `temp_massive` в это время не инициализирован и содержит мусор.

Comment: Понял. А то что temp_massive содержит мусор это плохо? Какой вред это несет?

Comment: @Владимир: Само по себе это не плохо, пока от этого ничего не зависит. Но это становится плохо, когда/если вы начинаете лезть в элементы массива, содержащие мусор и работать с этим мусором. Например, у вас в коде сразу же произойдет `strcmp(temp_el, temp_massive[j])` в тот момент, когда `temp_massive[j]` содержит мусор. Это бессмыслица.

Comment: @Владимир: Чтение мусорных значений запрещено стандартом, и компилятор имеет право в любой момент «наказать» вас за это. Просто не делайте так.

Comment: Хорошо, то есть можно инициализировать массив, например нулевыми значениями?

Comment: @Владимир: Если логика вашего кода не рухнет от этого, то можно, конечно. Например, вы выяснили, разрешено ли `strcmp` с `nullptr`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp Запрещено. Значит, вам, возможно, придётся пересмотреть алгоритм.

Comment: @Владимир: Нет. Лучше обратить внимание на тот факт, что инициализированная часть массива `temp_massive` у вас описывается переменной `index`. Соответственно все циклы поиска в массиве `temp_massive` должны идти от `0` до `index`, а не до `size`.

Comment: @Владимир: Оффтопик: на английском слово «massive» означает «массивный». Русское слово «массив» переводится на английский как «array».

Comment: @Владимир: Другими словами, на самой первой итерации внешнего цикла вы вообще не должны даже и пытаться обращаться к массиву `temp_massive`, ибо в этот момент `index` равен 0, то есть массив `temp_massive` фактически "пуст" и заглядывать туда незачем.

Comment: А почему от 0 до index? если я же могу не знать сколько уникальних символов цикл найдет, он может даже не найти дубликатов, тогда index будет равен size.

Comment: @Владимир: Ну так именно этим вы и занимаетесь - постепенно накапливаете в массиве `temp_massive` уникальные элементы. С появлением нового уникального элемента он добавляется в конец `temp_massive` и `index` увеличивается на 1. Если во входном массиве все элементы уникальны, то *в конечном итоге* `index` станет равен `size`. Как и должно быть. Не вижу проблем.

Comment: А-а-а. Понял, наконец-то :) Спасибо за помощь!